# python multithreading error

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a loop, in each loop, I put 4 threads in as following:

```
for k in range(0, len(result), 4):

    current_selection = result[k:k+4]  # this is a 4x1 array

    thread_list = []

    for i in current_selection:
        # Instantiates the thread
        # (i) does not make a sequence, so (i,)
        t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(i,))

        # Sticks the thread in a list so that it remains accessible
        thread_list.append(t)

        # Starts threads
        for thread in thread_list:
            thread.start()

        # This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is terminated.
        # From http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects
        for thread in thread_list:
            thread.join()
```

After the first loop, Thread number keeps increasing. Do I need a special way to clean the thread ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think that is the purpose of threading. It will not wait for the completion of previous thread and keeps on running the new thread and hence the for loop will keep on running.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. How can I run four threads simultaneously for each loop and move to another new loop? Since I have 4-core computer.

Comment: After each prepared thread, you are starting all threads and then waiting for them to end. That means that some of them are started and joined more than once. Shouldn't that be done only once per `for k in..` loop? BTW: `thread_list = [Thread(target=f, args=(i,)) for i in current_selection]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid of the array is too long such that I proposed the original approach and it is not working. Now just put my long array in the thread function and it works.

```
    current_selection = result  # this is a 15,000x1 array

    thread_list = []

    # Instantiates the thread
    # (i) does not make a sequence, so (i,)
    t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(selection,))

    # Sticks the thread in a list so that it remains accessible
    thread_list.append(t)

    # Starts threads
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()

    # This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is terminated.
    # From http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
```